# How to handle spacebar keydown

Tags: c#, windows-8

It seems that the keydown event does not handle spacebar presses unless the control has focus.  How do I, though?

I am using c# and I am making a windows store app, if it matters.

Comment: What do you wish to happen when the Spacebar is pressed?

Comment: i want it to fire an event

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what code you have within your project already but I'd recommend some JQuery along the lines of:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 0) {
  console.log('Space pressed, here is my event');
  }
});
```

As the event is bound to a Window event, it will find it regardless of whether an input field is focused or not.

Comment: Could you not use WinJS to get JQuery up and running for your Windows Store App?

Comment: Bear with me..I'll see if I can try a C# approach

Comment: I would prefer not having to combine languages.  Considering that the problem is rather simple, I feel like their should be a pure c# solution.  If all else fails I'll use your answer

Comment: No worries, I'll see what I can work out. :) My mind automatically thought JQuery as a Spacebar press is purely a clientside interaction and therefore Jquery seemed like the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
```

captures all key events.